# Cannot statically analyse 'require(..., ...)' in line in react

Tags: reactjs

In my project I placed all my .json files in one folder and exporting in index.js like below

```
module.exports = {
    get en() { return require('./strings/en.json') },
    get fr() { return require('./strings/fr.json')},
}
```

placed all my labels in english version in en.json and french labels in fr.json now I want to include error codes in diffrent json file and include in en.

When I tried to

```
module.exports = {
    get en() { return require('./strings/en.json','./strings/en_errorCodes.json') },
    get fr() { return require('./strings/fr.json','./strings/fr_errorCodes.json')},
}
```

it is giving "Cannot statically analyse 'require(..., ...)' in line 9".

Please help me.

Comment: `require` cannot take multiple parameters. Load files separately and then merge the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can return multiple json files like that. You should try to combine both of the json files together and then return them. This should look something like this:

```
get en() { 
    var text = require('./strings/en.json');
    var errorCode = require('./strings/en_errorCodes.json');
    return Object.assign({}, text, errorCode);
 }
```

Comment: why not just return an object literal?

Comment: Because you need to combine the 2 objects? How would you just return 1 object literal when you need to combine the 2 objects in 1?

Comment: `return {text, errorCode}` or even `return {text: require(...), errorCode: require(...)`

Comment: Using the method you're suggesting would create a new object with as key values text & errorCode. The problem here is that we need to combine all the values of the text and errorCode object. If we use Object.assign it'll create a new object with all the keys of the objects it's created from.

Comment: Right I didn't see that comma there.

Answer (score -4):

Instead of using *require *, use ajax to read JSON files. You can use

axios.get(apiUrl + input.value) 
    .then(function (response) { 
        pokemonName.innerHTML =            response.data.forms[0].name;    pokemonImage.src = response.data.sprites.front_default; }) .catch(function (error) { pokemonName.innerHTML = "(An error has occurred.)"; pokemonImage.src = ""; })